# Get Online Users List with ejabberd using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm new with ejabberd. I have created a few users with it. Is there a way to get the list of online users with a Javascript function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

My ejabberd does not return a list of users online, yours may differ. If you are just starting with this, you may find it a bit easier to make user of strophe.js to help you get started.

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html

```
<iq type="get" to="jab.yourjabberserver.com"> 
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/> 
</iq>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I'm understanding the HTML code in your answer. Can you explain it a bit ?

Comment: Without knowing how you are attempting to communicate with the server I really cannot create an example of a script. You need to create the xml above (or in any XEP protocol for that matter) and send to the server via your script. The "to" is your jabber server address. With your script functions, you also need to create a function that listens for a response so you can eval the responses and manage the user interaction from there.